# How to update the value of a variable being used in a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In a java program, I am running same function across multiple threads.
What I want to do is this--

1. Identify specific running threads-- eg if there are 2 running threads how can I access one of those threads from an external function? (The external function is part of the same java app  that has the threads)
2. Suppose there is a variable named "x" that is being used across both the threads above. Can I store and retrieve separate values for "x" in thread1 and thread2? Is this the default behaviour for any variable used in a thread?
3. Access/update values of variables in a specific thread-- eg I wish to update value of "x" as it is being used in "thread 1".
4. Terminate one (specific) running thread. Eg I wish to terminate Thread1 (from the 2 running threads above).

Comment: you mean cross thread access ?

Comment: no i mean access to variables/ specific threads from a function that can be invoked separate from the running threads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for

1. There are couple of Ways to do this. You can either;
   A Util class named `ThreadUtil` and inside have a `static Set<Thread>`. You can add the threads you create to set and remove whenever the thread finishes executing.
   Or you can extend from `ThreadPoolExecutor` and override methods `beforeExecute`, `afterExecute` methods to do the same thing above. The you can use the set to get the running threads. You can use a map if you want to store and retrieve by name.
2. This is possible by using `ThreadLocal` class. See [this](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/usage-of-threadlocal-in-java.html) post on how to use `ThreadLocal`
3. Possible with `ThreadLocal`
4. You can make use of a Flag (`boolean stop`) in the thread to do this, and a method to set this flag to `true`